# overloaded streams and arithmetic operations problem

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stream

I have got problem with overloaded operator+ and stream<<. I have class with overloaded operators:

```
FuzzyNumber& FuzzyNumber::add(FuzzyNumber B)
{
    FuzzyNumber fuzzyResult;

    fuzzyResult.setA(this -> getA() + B.getA() );
    fuzzyResult.setB(this -> getB() + B.getB() );
    fuzzyResult.setC(this -> getC() + B.getC() );

    return fuzzyResult;
}

FuzzyNumber& operator+(FuzzyNumber& A, FuzzyNumber& B)
{
    return A.add(B);
}

All fields inside class are double type. Here is overloaded ostream operator>>

ostream& FuzzyNumber::streamWrite(ostream& outStream)
{
    outStream << "( "
              << this -> getA() << ", "
              << this -> getB() << ", "
              << this -> getC() << ")";

    return outStream;
}



ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, FuzzyNumber& fuzzyNumber)
{
    fuzzyNumber.streamWrite(outStream);
    return outStream;
}
```

It is intend to print something like that (3, 4.3, 5.1) when i type cout << fuzzyNumber;. It works fine, furthermore this also works fine:

```
FuzzyNumber fuzzyNumber = numA + numB;
cout << "A + B = " << fuzzyNumber << endl;
```

where `numA` and `numB` are FuzzyNumber types.
Although program stops running when I replace above line with this:

```
cout << "A + B = " << (numA + numB) << endl;
```

Maybe it is something wrong with default operator=, but there are no dynamic variables in this class, so it shouldn't.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Define "stops running".  Do you mean it crashes?  Locks up?  Doesn't compile?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops running"?

Answer (score 3):

Inside operator+ you returned a reference to a stack variable. Your compiler should have warned you for this obvious instance.

```
FuzzyNumber FuzzyNumber::add(FuzzyNumber B) const
{
    FuzzyNumber fuzzyResult;

    fuzzyResult.setA(this -> getA() + B.getA() );
    fuzzyResult.setB(this -> getB() + B.getB() );
    fuzzyResult.setC(this -> getC() + B.getC() );

    return fuzzyResult;
}

FuzzyNumber operator+(const FuzzyNumber& A, const FuzzyNumber& B)
{
    return A.add(B);
}
```

This code should solve your problem. I also added some proper const correctness.

Comment: operator+ cannot be const, because it is a nonmember function, but it works anyway. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Phil: Oh yeah. Forgot to notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
FuzzyNumber FuzzyNumber::add(FuzzyNumber const &B) const
{
  FuzzyNumber fuzzyResult;

  fuzzyResult.setA(this -> getA() + B.getA() );
  fuzzyResult.setB(this -> getB() + B.getB() );
  fuzzyResult.setC(this -> getC() + B.getC() );

  return fuzzyResult;
}


FuzzyNumber operator+(FuzzyNumber const & A, FuzzyNumber const & B)
{
  FuzzyNumber res(A);
  res.add(B);
  return res;
}
```

and

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, FuzzyNumber const & fuzzyNumber)
{
    fuzzyNumber.streamWrite(outStream);
    return outStream;
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to make your FuzzyNumber::streamWrite() const!

Answer (score 0):

Temporaries can not be bound to non-const references, only to constant ones. The overload of `operator<<` takes a non-const reference, so it doesn't work for temporaries. It should take the `FuzzyNumber` by **const** reference instead:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, const FuzzyNumber& fuzzyNumber) {
   ...
}
```

This additionally means that `FuzzyNumber`'s `streamWrite()` and `getA()` through `getC()` should also be declared constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` function returns a reference to a local that will cease to exist, causing undefined behavior. The `add` function should return by value to avoid this.